# Python: seaborn how to split in various lines 20 subplots

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this code and the `subjective_corr1` are 10 heatmaps built with seaborn (e.g. `subjective_corr1 = outmyplot.corr()` using Person correlation.
The result I get is "correct" but he puts all 10 sublots in one line and it adds the cbar at the end like [image]

```
f,(ax1,ax2,ax3, ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9,ax10,axcb) = plt.subplots(1,11, 
        gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.08]})
ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax9,ax10)
g1 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr1,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True, cbar=False,ax=ax1)
g1.set_ylabel("")
g1.set_xlabel("")
g2 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr2,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,cbar=False,ax=ax2)
g2.set_ylabel("")
g2.set_xlabel("")
g2.set_yticks([])
g3 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr3,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,cbar=False,ax=ax3)
g3.set_ylabel("")
g3.set_xlabel("")
g3.set_yticks([])
g4 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr4,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True, cbar=False,ax=ax4)
g4.set_ylabel("")
g4.set_xlabel("")
g5 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr6,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,cbar=False,ax=ax5)
g5.set_ylabel("")
g5.set_xlabel("")
g5.set_yticks([])
g6 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr7,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,cbar=False,ax=ax6)
g6.set_ylabel("")
g6.set_xlabel("")
g6.set_yticks([])
g7 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr8,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True, cbar=False,ax=ax7)
g7.set_ylabel("")
g7.set_xlabel("")
g8 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr9,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,cbar=False,ax=ax8)
g8.set_ylabel("")
g8.set_xlabel("")
g8.set_yticks([])
g9 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr10,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,cbar=False,ax=ax9)
g9.set_ylabel("")
g9.set_xlabel("")
g9.set_yticks([])
g10 = sns.heatmap(subjective_corr11,vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',annot=True,ax=ax10, cbar_ax=axcb)
g10.set_ylabel("")
g10.set_xlabel("")
g10.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

but I want to split into two lines (with cbar at the end of all lines) like this [image] and I literally tried everithing but without luck. Actually there are 20 subplots to divide into 4 rows of 5 sublot each but I just wonder how to split subplots, but I cannot understand how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found the solution:the point was to write like this.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,12))

#  subplot #1
plt.subplot(4,5,1)
plt.title('PIE')
sns.heatmap(subjective_corr1,  vmin=-1, vmax=1,cmap='coolwarm',   annot=True)
```

and then add all the plots that you want simply adding the otner 19 subplots
and then closing with `plot.show()`